# javascript submit function freezes the custom css loader in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, spinner

In safari, when I am submitting a form on click of button and calling a function which should show a custom css loader and then a javascript submit method gets executed and I get the data.
But when I click on the button, the loader appears but it does not spin (the entire page get freeze) and after some time, the loader disappears and the data gets populated.
In Chrome it is working fine.

I am not sure wether the issue is with css or the call which I am making because if I only call the showLoader() and commenting the submit method, the loader works fine and the same loader works fine in other calls.

```
function showLoader(){
  $('#loader').show();
}
function submit(){
  showLoader();
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question but it sounds like the form is being submitted and a new page is being loaded. Or is there something that is handling the `onsubmit` event?

Comment: After submitting the form,an entire html is coming as a response.

Comment: Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Then I guess that the difference in behaviour is down to the way the two browsers handle page navigation. Probably little to nothing you can do.

Comment: Using ajax call fixed the issue.May be helpful for someone.Thanks